# Preserve redux store while updating different components

Tags: reactjs, redux

Here is my reducer file.

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
case AppConstants.getMenuItems:
  return {
    ...state,
    isLoading: true
  }
case AppConstants.getMenuItemsSuccess:
  return {
    ...state,
    menu_items: action.menu_items,
    menu_items_copy: action.menu_items,
    unmapped: false,
    isLoading: false
  }
case AppConstants.getAddonsItems:
  return {
    ...state,
    isLoading: true
  }
case AppConstants.getAddonsItemsSuccess:
  return {
    ...state,
    menu_items: action.addon_items,
    isLoading: false
  }

  case AppConstants.showAllProducts:
   return {
    ...state,
    menu_items: state.menu_items,
    unmapped: false
  }

 case AppConstants.getUnmappedMenuItemsSuccess:
  return {
    ...state,
    unmapped: true,
    menu_items_copy: state.menu_items,
    menu_items: state.menu_items_copy.filter(data => {
      data.productList = data.productList.filter(
        id => id.brandProductSkuList[0].productSKUId.length === 36,
      );
      return data.productList.length !== 0;
    })
  }
```

Now When I click on unmapped filter it shows the filtered data but after unmapped when I click allProducts it still gives the unmapped data ,since in unmap function the state (menu_items) is updated.So how do I show the original data in allproducts. And in my UI ,I am using (this.props.menu_items) ,so I have to update that only.[image: Here is the image of UI]
What I want to do is ,when Categories is clicked it should show allproducts and unmapped for that and similarly for Addons.

Comment: You should ideally have the entire data in redux store and filter our the content in the component rather than updating the store itself

Comment: Yes thanks that worked

Comment: Glad you could fix the issue, you can add an answer to your question for reference of readers as to how you fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the unmapped functionality from the reducer and placed it in my component as follows-

```
render() {
let count = 0;
return (
  <div className="table" >
    <div className="container" >
      <div className="show-grid row">
        <div className="col-xs-3 head1">Products</div>
        <div className="col-xs-3 head2">Variants</div>
        <div className="col-xs-3 head3">P.S ID</div>
        <div className="col-xs-3 head4">Updated</div>
      </div>
      {this.props.dataProp.length == 0 &&
        <div id="noproducts"> No Products Available</div>
      }
      {this.props.dataProp.map((data => {
        let dataNew = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        if (this.props.unmapped === true) {
          dataNew.productList = dataNew.productList.filter(
            id => id.brandProductSkuList[0].productSKUId.length === 36
          );
          if (dataNew.productList.length > 0)
            return (<Category key={data.categoryName + uuidv4()} categoryData={dataNew} />);
        }
        else if (this.props.unmapped === false && data.productList.length > 0) {
          return (<Category key={data.categoryName + uuidv4()} categoryData={data} />);
        }
      }))
      }
    </div>
  </div >
 )
}
```

---

I took a flag for unmap to show the products when it is false and when it is true.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making a conceptual mistake when altering `menu_items` upon unmapped items request. It is quite useful to think about your redux store as if it was some kind of old-good SQL database and design it accordingly. You do not remove rows which are not to be included in a `select` operation from your database. They are still living inside a table, they are just not selected.

Same story with `redux` apps. Let `getMenuItemsSuccess` be the only place where `menu_items` are actually mutated. Then do one of the following:

1. Introduce `unmapped_items` field in your store which will be update on `getUnmappedMenuItemsSuccess` action.
2. Same but do your filtering after data is loaded from back-end. In this case `getUnmappedMenuItemsSuccess` will just switch the source of items without doing any additional work.
3. Do your filtering in `Component` code.